# I think I've got my jframe right in this program, but not sure

Tags: java, swing

I think I've got the jframe right in this program, but why is nothing appearing when I run it?
I have two different classes, here is my first. Just ignore the last method where I'm going to draw a rectangle with circles in it for a stoplight.

Here's my code.

```
package trafficlight;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class TrafficLight {

private int goDuration;
private int stopDuration;
private int warnDuration;

public enum State {STOP, GO, WARN};
public Color GO_COLOR = Color.green;
public Color STOP_COLOR = Color.red;
public Color OFF_COLOR = Color.darkGray;
public Color WARNING_COLOR = Color.yellow;
private State currentState;


public TrafficLight() {
goDuration =  2;
stopDuration = 2;
warnDuration =1;
currentState =  State.GO;
}

public void changeLight(){
if(currentState  == State.GO){
        currentState = State.WARN;
}
if(currentState == State.WARN){
        currentState = State.STOP;
}
if(currentState == State.STOP){
        currentState = State.GO;
}
}


public int getGoDuration() {
    return goDuration;
}

public void setGoDuration(int goDuration) {
    this.goDuration = goDuration;
}

public int getStopDuration() {
    return stopDuration;
}

public void setStopDuration(int stopDuration) {
    this.stopDuration = stopDuration;
}

public int getWarnDuration() {
    return warnDuration;
}

public void setWarnDuration(int warnDuration) {
    this.warnDuration = warnDuration;
}

public State getCurrentState() {
    return currentState;
}

public void setCurrentState(State currentState) {
    this.currentState = currentState;
}
public int getCurrentDuration(){
    int duration = 0;
    if (currentState == State.STOP){
        duration = stopDuration;
    }
    if (currentState == State.GO){
        duration = goDuration;
    }
    if (currentState == State.WARN){
        duration = warnDuration;
    }
    return duration;
}
public void draw(Graphics canvas) {
    canvas.drawRect(125,185,100,250);
    canvas.drawOval(145,200,60,60);
    canvas.drawOval(145,280,60,60);
    canvas.drawOval(145,360,60,60);

    if (currentState == State.STOP){

    }


}

}
```

Here's my second class.

```
package trafficlight;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TrafficLightDriver extends JFrame {

private static TrafficLight light;

public void message() {
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TrafficLightDriver myFrame = new TrafficLightDriver();
    int delay, answer;
    String valueString;

    do {
        valueString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the green light delay? (1.. 10)");
        light.setGoDuration(Integer.parseInt(valueString));
        valueString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the yellow light delay? (1.. 10)");
        light.setWarnDuration(Integer.parseInt(valueString));
        valueString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the red light delay? (1.. 10)");
        light.setStopDuration(Integer.parseInt(valueString));
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            delay = light.getCurrentDuration();
            Wait.manySec(delay);
            light.changeLight();
            myFrame.repaint();
        }
        answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to run the light again?",
                null, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    } while (answer == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
    System.exit(0);
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics canvas) {
    light.draw(canvas);
}

public TrafficLightDriver() {  //constructor
    setSize(350, 600);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    light = new TrafficLight();
    setVisible(true);
}
}
```

here's my wait class

```
package trafficlight;

public class Wait {

public static void oneSec() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}

public static void manySec(long s) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(s * 1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}

public static void tenthOfSec(long s) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(s * 100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I suspect that your loop isn't doing you any favours

Comment: What is `Wait.manySec(delay);`? I've never seen anything like this before. Do you have a Wait class with a static `manySec(...)` method in it that you're not showing us? Does this call a `Thread.sleep(...)`? If so this will freeze your GUI rendering it useless.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I do have a wait class. I'll edit it into the original post.

Comment: That's kind of relevant. I fear that it and the loop that @MadProgrammer is talking about (that the Wait.manySec(...) is called in) is messing you up. Consider using a Swing Timer if you want a delay.

Comment: Does my first class look alright?

Comment: I know this is kind of the "is it plugged in?"-question, but: You are properly starting the second class when you run this, not by accident the empty main-method of the first class?

Comment: Yes I am, I'm starting using the second class.

Comment: I was right -- you're calling `Thread.sleep`. Don't do that, but instead Google the tutorial on use of Swing Timers and use one.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should avoid overriding `paint` of top level containers, instead, you should use something like `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method.
2. The paint process is a chained series of methods, all which build ontop of each other to generate the output, the moment you break this change, you allow for introduction of artifacts and irregularities to appear.  Make sure you are honouring the paint chain by always calling `super.paintXxx`
3. Swing is a single threaded framework.  That is, there is a single thread that is responsible for processing all the events within the system, including repaint requests.  This means that if you block this thread for any reason, you will prevent from processing any new events which will make you program appear as if it has hung.  You are also required to ensure that any updates to the UI are made from within the context of this thread.

Start by having a read through

- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)
- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Now, I don't know how you `Wait` class works so I can't comment on that portion, but your `TrafficLight` isn't updating itself to reflect it's current state...

**Updated...**

You also have two `main` methods which is very confusing.  The application logic appears to be in `TrafficLightDriver`, you should make sure you are running this class when you execute your program.

There is a logic problem in your `changeLight` method

```
public void changeLight(){
    if(currentState  == State.GO){
        currentState = State.WARN;
    }
    if(currentState == State.WARN){
        currentState = State.STOP;
    }
    if(currentState == State.STOP){
        currentState = State.GO;
    }
}
```

Basically, what this is says is...

if currentState is GO, set currentState to WARN...
if currentState is WARN, set currentState to STOP... 
if currentState is STOP, set currentState to GO...

Given the fact that the default state is `GO`, when you call this method, the state will never be changed to anything other the `GO`.  Instead, you should be using an `if-else` statement

```
public void changeLight() {
    if (currentState == State.GO) {
        currentState = State.WARN;
    } else if (currentState == State.WARN) {
        currentState = State.STOP;
    } else if (currentState == State.STOP) {
        currentState = State.GO;
    }
}
```

**Updated**

Rendering the lights themselves comes a lot down to personal preferences, for example, I might be tempted to do something like....

```
switch (getCurrentState()) {
    case GO:
        canvas.setColor(GO_COLOR);
        canvas.drawOval(145,360,60,60);
        break;
    case WARN:
        canvas.setColor(WARNING_COLOR);
        canvas.drawOval(145,280,60,60);
        break;
    case STOP:
        canvas.setColor(STOP_COLOR);
        canvas.drawOval(145,200,60,60);
        break;
}
canvas.setColor(OFF_COLOR);
canvas.drawRect(125,185,100,250);
canvas.drawOval(145,200,60,60);
canvas.drawOval(145,280,60,60);
canvas.drawOval(145,360,60,60);
```

This will fill the light that is active, but then renders everything else over the top, so the light is always outlined

Comment: Thank you very much this helped a ton, cant thank you enough.

Comment: Don't forget, have fun ;)

Comment: Now, I'm drawing the stoplight, and doing the colors themselves, do you think you could help me with it really quick? I have the stoplight drawn and the three circles drawn, I just need to make it to where the colors change to which one is lit up. So the currentState light should be colored, but the other two should be set to something like OFF_COLOR, I know how to draw the light but I've never done the filling before, and setting them to the OFF_COLOR confuses me..  Also does my duration method look alright there?

Comment: I'll edit my code above to what I have for this draw() method in my first class.

Answer (score 0):

You call System.exit().  That kills the java VM and ends the program.  Remove that line.

If you want to control the behavior of your program when the JFrame is closed use frame.setDefaultCloseOperation().